How to reduce the required storage space for large indexes and large PostgreSQL tables to improve and ensure performance?
The Situation (updated):
I have 3 PostgreSQL tables (PostgreSQL Version 14.9) that are used to store sensor data from currently 2670 data points. The data was written to the database (blocks of data for 3 days) with automatically generated insert statements in the form:
INSERT INTO monitoring_data.time_series_numerical (timestamp, property_id, value) 
VALUES ('timestamp', 'property_id', 'value')
...
ON CONFLICT (timestamp, property_id) DO NOTHING;

This ultimately led to the database becoming slower and slower to the point that new storage space had to be released so that it could be accessed again.
The disk space usage of the 3 tables:



oid
table_schema
table_name
number_of_rows
total_row_bytes
row_bytes
total_bytes
index_bytes
toast_bytes
table_bytes
total
index
table
toast




22220
monitoring_data
time_series
5.5084934e+08
226.11499436726209
97.18495597524046
124555296768
71006248960
NULL
53549047808
116 GB
66 GB
50 GB
NULL


22230
monitoring_data
time_series_numerical
5.0103974e+08
242.67533732942616
108.90748283270925
121589989376
67007979520
NULL
54582009856
113 GB
62 GB
51 GB
NULL


22238
monitoring_data
time_series_alphabetical
3.25614e+07
255.89714840902735
110.47100539466943
8332369920
4734271488
8192
3598090240
7946 MB
4515 MB
3431 MB
8192 bytes



The 3 tables via CREATE script from pgAdmin 4:
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monitoring_data.time_series
(
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    property_id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT time_series_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("timestamp", property_id),
    CONSTRAINT time_series_property_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
        REFERENCES monitoring_data.properties (property_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)


varchar(255), e.g. c0022:93EA6CCA3B7D1829_AnalogInput1.status.voltage), which is used as identification for the data point

time_series_numerical:
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monitoring_data.time_series_numerical
(
    -- Inherited from table monitoring_data.time_series: "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    -- Inherited from table monitoring_data.time_series: property_id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    value double precision NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT time_series_numerical_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("timestamp", property_id),
    CONSTRAINT time_series_numerical_timestamp_property_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY ("timestamp", property_id)
        REFERENCES monitoring_data.time_series ("timestamp", property_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
    INHERITS (monitoring_data.time_series)

time_series_alphabetical: Same as time_series_numerical except the value column
value text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,

To ensure that the foreign key constraint is fulfilled when writing records to one of the inheriting tables, a trigger was created in conjunction with a function that executes the following function before the INSERT of each record:
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO monitoring_data.time_series (timestamp, property_id)
    SELECT NEW.timestamp, NEW.property_id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM monitoring_data.time_series 
        WHERE timestamp = NEW.timestamp
        AND property_id = NEW.property_id 
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;

The time_series table should be used to simplify access to measured values in the underlying tables, regardless of the data type, and to enable all timestamp and property_id entries to be stored together and only once.
As I have already noted, this is not working as expected and has resulted in the data being stored twice (once in the time_series table and once in the respective table for the measurement), and in the time_series table itself, each entry even exists twice.
Query example:
SELECT *
FROM monitoring_data.time_series_numerical
WHERE property_id = 'c0022:9FF441820C58912B_HeatPump.configuration.flowTemperature'  -- Replace <your_property_id> with the actual ID
AND timestamp >= '2024-09-01 00:00:00'
AND timestamp < '2024-09-02 00:00:00'
ORDER BY timestamp;

Result with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS):
"Index Scan using time_series_numerical_pkey on monitoring_data.time_series_numerical  (cost=0.57..1153041.19 rows=4516 width=72) (actual time=0.516..633099.399 rows=5725 loops=1)"
"  Output: ""timestamp"", property_id, value"
"  Index Cond: ((time_series_numerical.""timestamp"" >= '2024-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (time_series_numerical.""timestamp"" < '2024-09-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((time_series_numerical.property_id)::text = 'c0022:9FF441820C58912B_HeatPump.configuration.flowTemperature'::text))"
"  Buffers: shared read=199057"
"Settings: search_path = 'monitoring_data'"
"Planning Time: 0.485 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 2"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 2.138 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.000 ms, Emission 0.000 ms, Total 2.138 ms"
"Execution Time: 633108.973 ms"

Before I begin to implement a solution for this problem, I am seeking advice here, as I am just starting to work with PostgreSQL.
Thoughts on solutions and questions:
I currently have two ideas to tackle the problem, but I would like to know what other options I have and what would make sense or be considered best practice for my use case.

Delete all entries from the time_series table, remove the foreign key constraints from both inheriting tables, as well as the triggers and functions, so that access via the time_series table to the inheriting tables is still possible, but significantly less storage space is used.

Use partitioning to split the data across multiple tables based on the timestamp in order to speed up queries.


It is still unclear to me why the indexes take up so much space and how I can reduce that.
Additional info:
PostgreSQL Version 14.9; there are no additional indexes besides the primary keys; all indexes are b-tree indexes; there are no dead tuples; autovacuum is enabled; extensions: postgis, fuzzystrmatch, uuid-ossp; it was decided that time_series_numerical and time_series_alphabetical should be separated


Read Do not use images. 2) How was the size data gathered? Add as text update to question text. 3) Add to question what version of Postgres are you using as well as any extensions you may be using. 4) Do you have autovacuum enabled?


Performance depends on so many things, and table or index size are just two of the less important things. Please share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, the query that is slow and the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query. All in plain text.

Please review [mre]. Abstract descriptions don't provide enough detail for concrete reasoning about specific issues; however, from what has been provided, it seems that the major source of table bloat is due to using property_id as part of the keys. Restructure the schema to have a properties table with a BIGINT ID column and the property name and change the other tables to reference properties.id instead of the property name. The changes should reduce the storage size by at least 80%.

Does time_series provide information that isn't also available from time_series_numerical and time_series_alphabetical? From the row counts you provided, there seems to be ~1.7M rows in time_series that don't have a corresponding row in either time_series_numerical or time_series_alphabetical.   Are those rows due to empty sensor data? Why are numerical and alphabetical data stored in separate tables? Consider storing both in time_series and dropping the other two tables.

Yes, I'd just get rid of time_series. That would get rid of the redundancy. It is normal for indexes to be large. Perhaps you can get rid of some unnecessary indexes?

Thanks for the info. I updated the question (Thanks @LaurenzAlbe for formatting it) and included DDLs and an explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) result for an example query. I will get rid of the time_series table and using a BIGINT ID for the property_id's also makes sense to me.

The index is defined on (property_id, timestamp) in that order, right? If yes, your index is probably bloated out of shape. Try VACUUMing the table. If that does not help, REINDEX INDEX the index.

You state, "it was decided that time_series_numerical and time_series_alphabetical should be separated". What was the rationale for that decision? Should the insert into sensor_data have been into time_series? Avoid using keywords, such as timestamp as identifiers.

The reason for the decision was that there is far less data that is alphabetical and this data is needed less frequently. What would be the advantage of having everything stored in one table? And yes, you are right, sensor_data should be time_series. I accidentally copied the code for the function from a draft.. The code is the same, the keywords are different. I will change timestamp to measured_at.

The OP's original design icludes the full property name (called property_id in the post) with each sample. The example name
is 62 characters long, which seems to be a reasonable estimate for the mean name length given the table statistics that were provided.
Repeating the name with each sample is an extremely inefficient use of space.
The following demonstrates an approach that reduces the required space by replacing the property name in each sample with a reference to a properties table.
This approach results in an order of magnitude improvement in storage efficiency. Some column names have been changed to avoid using PostgreSQL keywords.
Below are the table definitions (time_series_alphabetical is omitted since it is nearly identical to time_series_numerical):
CREATE TABLE properties (
  id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  property_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  CONSTRAINT properties_updated_at_ck CHECK (created_at <= updated_at)
);

CREATE TABLE time_series_numerical (
  sample_timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ,
  property_id BIGINT REFERENCES properties (id),
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  sample_value DOUBLE PRECISION,
  CONSTRAINT time_series_numerical_pk PRIMARY KEY (property_id, sample_timestamp),
  CONSTRAINT time_series_numerical_updated_at_ck CHECK (created_at <= updated_at)
);

The audit columns (created_at and updated_at) can be omitted if there isn't a need or desire to track those attributes. Timestamps are declared as
TIMESTAMPTZ as recommended at Date/Time storage. The primary key
for time_series_numerical is (property_id, sample_timestamp) to facilitate efficient retrieval by property. If retrieval by sample_timestamp
is also common, then an additional index should be added with sample_timestamp as the first attribute.
The following uses a single SQL statement to insert a set of samples with the ability to automatically add properties that have not previously
been recorded:
WITH
  samples AS (
    SELECT
      ts::TIMESTAMPTZ AS sample_timestamp,
      property_name,
      sample_value
    FROM
      (
        VALUES
          ('2024-01-01 00:00:00', 'prop1', 1),
          ('2024-01-01 01:00:00', 'prop1', 2),
          ('2024-01-01 00:00:00', 'prop2', 3),
          ('2024-01-01 00:00:00', 'prop4', 4),
          ('2024-01-01 00:00:00', 'prop3', 5)
      ) v (ts, property_name, sample_value)
  ),
  new_properties AS (
    INSERT INTO properties (property_name)
    SELECT DISTINCT property_name
      FROM samples
      ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
      RETURNING id, property_name
  )
INSERT INTO time_series_numerical AS tsn (sample_timestamp, property_id, sample_value)
SELECT s.sample_timestamp,
       COALESCE(p.id,
                (SELECT np.id
                   FROM new_properties np
                   WHERE np.property_name = s.property_name)) AS property_id,
       s.sample_value
  FROM samples s
  LEFT JOIN properties p ON p.property_name = s.property_name
  ON CONFLICT (sample_timestamp, property_id)
    DO UPDATE SET sample_value = EXCLUDED.sample_value,
                  updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
         WHERE tsn.sample_value IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.sample_value;

The ON CONFLICT clause updates a previously recorded sample if the value has changed.
Running the following query demonstrates that each property has only been inserted once:
SELECT * FROM properties ORDER BY property_name;




id
created_at
updated_at
property_name




3
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
prop1


1
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
prop2


2
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
prop3


4
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
prop4



Samples along with their associated property name can be retrieved with the following query:
SELECT
  tsn.sample_timestamp,
  tsn.property_id,
  p.property_name,
  tsn.sample_value,
  tsn.created_at,
  tsn.updated_at
FROM
  time_series_numerical tsn
  JOIN properties p ON p.id = tsn.property_id;




sample_timestamp
property_id
property_name
sample_value
created_at
updated_at




2024-01-01 00:00:00-05
3
prop1
1
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04


2024-01-01 01:00:00-05
3
prop1
2
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04


2024-01-01 00:00:00-05
1
prop2
3
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04


2024-01-01 00:00:00-05
4
prop4
4
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04


2024-01-01 00:00:00-05
2
prop3
5
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04
2024-09-22 15:16:27.151381-04



To demonstrate the improved storage efficiency, run the following block to generate synthetic data useful for exploring the effects of different indexing options and system settings
(on my 2017 MacBook Pro, this took ~1 hour to complete):
DO $BLOCK$
<<local>>
DECLARE
  num_properties CONSTANT INTEGER := 2670;
  property_name_length CONSTANT INTEGER := 50;
  sampling_interval CONSTANT INTERVAL := INTERVAL '15' SECOND;
  missed_sample_probability CONSTANT DOUBLE PRECISION := 0.006;
  sample_date_range CONSTANT TSTZRANGE :=  TSTZRANGE('2024-09-01'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
                                                     '2024-09-15'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
BEGIN
  TRUNCATE TABLE time_series_numerical;
  TRUNCATE TABLE properties CASCADE;
  PERFORM SETVAL('properties_id_seq', 1, FALSE);

  INSERT INTO properties(property_name)
  SELECT SUBSTRING(REPEAT(ENCODE(UUID_SEND(GEN_RANDOM_UUID()), 'HEX'),
                          CEIL(local.property_name_length / 16.0)::INTEGER),
                   local.property_name_length)
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, local.num_properties) gs(n);

  INSERT INTO time_series_numerical(sample_timestamp, property_id, sample_value)
  SELECT sample_times.sample_timestamp, props.id, RANDOM() * 10000
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, local.num_properties) props(id)
    CROSS JOIN GENERATE_SERIES(LOWER(local.sample_date_range),
                               UPPER(local.sample_date_range) - INTERVAL '0.000001' SECOND,
                               local.sampling_interval) sample_times(sample_timestamp)
    WHERE random() > local.missed_sample_probability;
END;
$BLOCK$ language plpgsql;

This resulted in 2670 rows in properties using ~352 KB for table data and ~440 KB for indexes and 214,017,381 rows in time_series_numerical using ~13.61 GB for table data and ~8.9 GB for indexes
(removing the audit columns, created_at and updated_at, reduces the table size by ~3.2 GB).
Two main factors contributed to the excessively long query time with the OP's original table structure: inefficient index scanning caused by index column order, and excessive block reads caused by low tuple density. Querying for an individual property would be considerably more efficient if the property column appeared first in the index definition since that would reduce the number of block reads required to access all of the related samples. Because the property names are very long, they require significantly more bytes than would be needed by an integer ID reference, which means significantly more block reads (for the OP's case, using an INTEGER reference would reduce the number of block reads by ~16 and using BIGINT by ~8). With the above table structure, query performance is improved by several orders of magnitude as demonstrated by the following:
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE)
SELECT
  tsn.sample_timestamp,
  tsn.property_id,
  p.property_name,
  tsn.sample_value,
  tsn.created_at,
  tsn.updated_at
FROM
  time_series_numerical tsn
  JOIN properties p ON p.id = tsn.property_id
WHERE p.property_name = '80c2bc53040057ac1fca90fa61a492e980c2bc53040057ac1fca90fa61a492e980c2bc53040057a'
  AND tsn.sample_timestamp >= '2024-09-01'::TIMESTAMP
  AND tsn.sample_timestamp < '2024-09-02'::TIMESTAMP;

QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop  (cost=196.53..21870.23 rows=5622 width=120) (actual time=3.191..11.325 rows=5723 loops=1)
  Output: tsn.sample_timestamp, tsn.property_id, p.property_name, tsn.sample_value, tsn.created_at, tsn.updated_at
  Buffers: shared hit=5768 read=2
  ->  Index Scan using properties_property_name_key on public.properties p  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=88) (actual time=0.637..0.641 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: p.id, p.created_at, p.updated_at, p.property_name
        Index Cond: (p.property_name = '80c2bc53040057ac1fca90fa61a492e980c2bc53040057ac1fca90fa61a492e980c2bc53040057a'::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.time_series_numerical tsn  (cost=196.25..21805.71 rows=5622 width=40) (actual time=2.544..7.690 rows=5723 loops=1)
        Output: tsn.sample_timestamp, tsn.property_id, tsn.created_at, tsn.updated_at, tsn.sample_value
        Recheck Cond: ((tsn.property_id = p.id) AND (tsn.sample_timestamp >= '2024-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (tsn.sample_timestamp < '2024-09-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Heap Blocks: exact=5723
        Buffers: shared hit=5767
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on time_series_numerical_pk  (cost=0.00..194.84 rows=5622 width=0) (actual time=1.574..1.575 rows=5723 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((tsn.property_id = p.id) AND (tsn.sample_timestamp >= '2024-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (tsn.sample_timestamp < '2024-09-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
              Buffers: shared hit=44
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=78 read=11
Planning Time: 9.076 ms
Execution Time: 11.783 ms

